# Submit form without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know this is a repost, and I have looked in mostly all other posts about the subject both using Ajax, jQuery and those not using a submit button in their form, but none of the answers doesn't seem to be working on my specific code.

I have the following form:

```
<ul id="btn_MyJobs" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li id="MyJobs_List" class="push">
  <form name="MyJobs" id="MyJobsForm" action="" method="post">
  <?php do { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="MyJob" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['cargo']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['cargo']; ?>"><br/><br/>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</form>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want the form to be submitted to the code below (**on the same page**), so that I can get the SQL Value String to use in my WHERE clause:

```
mysql_select_db($database_Connection, $Connection);
$query_Recordset_MyJobs = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE cargo = ".GetSQLValueString($_POST['MyJob'], 'text');
$Recordset_MyJobs = mysql_query($query_Recordset_MyJobs, $Connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset_MyJobs = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset_MyJobs);
$totalRows_Recordset_MyJobs = mysql_num_rows($Recordset_MyJobs);
```

But I want to submit the form **without refreshing the page**, so when the submit button is clicked, the form is sent to the SQL Value String but the page is not refreshing or loading.
So I have tried using Ajax as following:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#MyJobsForm').on('submit', function (e) {    

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#MyJobsForm').serialize(),
            success: function (data) 
            {
                alert('form was submitted');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I run the code, it shows me the alert message, but the call to the database is not receiving the data from the form. I figure there is something wrong with the Ajax code, but I can't figure out what. Can someone please help me submit the form without without refreshing the page?
Ajax isn't a necessity.

Comment: the ajax request makes a **new** request to the page, and returns the output in the data variable. it does **not** effect the currently rendered page.

Comment: AJAX (or, an asynchronous web request - people rarely use XML with them anymore so AJAX is usually a misnomer) is a necessity if you don't want to refresh the page.

What you need to do is use an input type=button and use the click event: $('#submitButton').click(... to run $.ajax(... because an input with type="submit" tells the browser to "refresh" the page onto the form's action. Or, as Flosculus mentioned, return false; should work.

Comment: Ajax shouldn't be used to submit to the same page. The data field you reference in success takes all return data. There is no good way for you to piece through the data and get a valid response. You should create a secondary php file that will be your target that returns your desired through echo or some other form of output response in php.

Comment: I want to say you could essentially do a replace of your body with `$('body').html(data)` if you wanted to query the same page that should override the section you're wanting.

Comment: With the right conditions on the server-side, there's no reason why a form cannot be submitted to the same page :)

Comment: It's not something you normally want to do. That's all I'm saying. try out the replace of body with the data and see if that helps you. If it doesn't try `$(document).html(data);`. I'm slightly shooting in the dark as I don't know if they work, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: There is no `url` attribute in this ajax call

Comment: @EoiFirst that's because he's submitting to the same page, on purpose.

Comment: Oh ok. Didn't know this practice

Comment: @EoiFirst `url` is optional and would do the same as a normal form would.

Comment: @Jacob I have now changed `input type` to button, and the Ajax now looks like this:
`$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () { `

But it is still not working?

Comment: Always keep an eye on the error console, especially JavaScript errors (shit+f5 in firefox and ctrl+shitf+j in chrome).

Comment: I have now tried all the answers, but none of them are working :-( And the error-console gave me nothing @Jacob.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of an ajax call that submits a form using a select change and will change the whole page from the response that it receives from the change. You can use something like this. You do not have to have a formal submit code. You do not even have to have a form. All you need is the values of the data that you want to submit. I would recommend to using a separate PHP file to actually call in your code and only replacing specific portions of the page.

```
$(document).on('change', '#insurecode', function(){
        var val = $('#groupnumtxt').val(), insure = $('#insurecode').val(), mbid = $('#mbid').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { groupnum: val, insurecode: insure, mbid: mbid }, // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data){
                switch(data){
                    $(document).html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Replace `$(document).html(data);` with `alert(data)` if it will make you more comfortable as to what I'm saying.

Comment: Should be noted you don't need to see my html or my php that goes through the script as it will return everything visibly returned and I'm not using this code in the manner you're mentioning. This would do it if I wanted to replace everything on my page with what is returned based on these values, but that isn't my goal for the current program I'm writing.